# Hadoop MapReduce set input recursive - method not found

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, mapreduce

I want to read the input from a directory where there are other directories and files inside those directories;

```
Input
    -Dir1
        -f11.txt
        -f12.txt
    -Dir2
        -f21.txt
        -f22.txt
```

I have to read the input recursively and the solution should be

```
FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);
```

But, I get the error `method not found for FileInputFormat`.

I'm using eclipse, the building path of the project contains the library `hadoop-core-2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.7.0.jar`; looking on the API of hadoop 2.6 ([1](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/index.html)), the FileInputFormat should have the `setInputDirRecursive(...)` method, but my library doesn't have it.

I tried looking online for that jar but I have not found a jar file that contains that method.

Besides, I downloaded the libraries from the container cloudera, in which the command `hadoop version` say `Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.7.0`, so it should be a valid jar.

Comment: are you getting it during compilation or you are getting run time?

Comment: The error comes up in compilation